# relation between reactive programming and react JS

Tags: reactjs, reactive-programming, reactive

there is a programming concept called **reactive programming**, and a variation of JS called **react JS**. is there any relation between these two?

Answer (score 4):

Reactive Programming is a programming paradigm and involves programming with asynchronous data streams. Many program languages implemented this paradigm and have tools for this. But React is a UI framework for build client side web applications. React JS also is a JavaScript Framework that used in many web applications.